# how can I avoid \underset shift following subscripts downwards

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, baseline

My example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\underset{\circ}{(\alpha_i)}^{\sigma}_n
\]

\[
\underset{\circ}{(\alpha_i)^{\sigma}_n}
\]

\end{document}
```

yields

[image: result of my latex code]

I want a mixture between both results. In the above picture, the \circ is centered as it should be, but the index n is too far below. In the second picture, the index n is correctly placed, but now the \circ is of course placed relative to the whole expression, which is inadvertent.

I think I would be able to work around this with some hacks (\phantom comes to mind), but is there a more elegant way to prevent \underset to shift the baseline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want `\underaccent`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}

\begin{document}

\[
\underaccent{\circ}{(\alpha_i)}^{\sigma}_n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem. I also like that the \circ is slightly smaller now.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote,

> I want a mixture between both results.

Since you're already the `amsmath` package, you could use its `\smash[b]{...}` macro and write

```
\smash[b]{\underset{\circ}{(\alpha_i)}}^{\sigma}_n
```

to achieve your objective.

Here's an MWE (minimum working example). The first term is as above, the second and third are from your posting.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'amsart' document class
\begin{document}
\[
\smash[b]{\underset{\circ}{(\alpha_i)}}^{\sigma}_n
\qquad 
\underset{\circ}{(\alpha_i)}^{\sigma}_n
\quad
\underset{\circ}{(\alpha_i)^{\sigma}_n}
\]
\end{document}
```